# Difference between Large Scale Scrum (LeSS) and Nexus Framework

Tags: scrum, agile, process-scaling, scaled, nexus

I am trying to understand the differences in the "process" between Less and Nexus; they seem very similar in the way they scale Scrum.

I am **not** trying to understand which one to select, but what would be the difference in the execution between LeSS and Nexus.

I checked this [Scaled scrum/agile frameworks (SAFe vs. Nexus vs. LeSS) comparison](https://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/17441/scaled-scrum-agile-frameworks-safe-vs-nexus-vs-less-comparison) but the offered comparison is on which one to select, not on **how** things are done in the framework.

Answer (score 2):

To understand the *how* bit you will need to study each individually. The good news is that all will talk about basically the same thing but with different terminologies. If you are familiar with Scrum, then understanding the *how* of any of the 3 should be fairly straightforward.

In case of Nexus, which is my favourite, you basically add additional events formal (like backlog refinement and nexus daily scrum), roles (like the nexus integration team), and artefacts (like the nexus sprint backlog).

Check out the [Nexus Guide](https://www.scrum.org/resources/nexus-guide) here but only if you are already well versed in Scrum.

Nexus provides an "exoskeleton" to Scrum and I would say its the most "lightweight" scaled Scrum framework.

Maybe others can add more on the how of SAFe and LeSS.

Comment: I am already well versed with Scrum, SAFe and LeSS, and know well the difference between them, but new to Nexus. The difference I don't see is how Nexus differs fro LeSS. Less also has backlog refinement and cross team synchronization and the equivalent of the nexus sprint backlog

Comment: The short answer is that they are not different. Terms differ. The extent of content differs and as a result the way the certification is done differs.

Answer (score 0):

For me it's like Nexus is an interface and LESS implements it.

Nexus tells what needs to be in your process, while LESS tells you how to do it (extended rules, mindset, examples, howtos)